# AWS Lambda Error When Deploying Golang Function via Zip File on Windows Machine

Tags: aws-lambda

I have created a simple program in order to try to upload onto AWS Lambda. Here is the snippet of the main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type Input struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Id      string `json:"id"`
}

func testLambdaFunc(ctx context.Context, input Input) (int64, error) {
    ts := time.Now().UnixMilli()

    fmt.Printf("Timestamp: %d\n\tInput ID: %s\n", ts, input.Id, input.Message)

    return ts, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(testLambdaFunc)
}
```

I have followed the instructions on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html#golang-package-windows to deploy a function onto AWS Lambda using a zip file.

The settings for the Lambda function created manually without any CLI are:
Runtime: Amazon Linux 2023
Architecture: x86_64

The command line used to generate the zip file is:

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64 
set CGO_ENABLED=0
go build -o bootstrap main.go
C:\Users\Test\go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe  -o myFunction.zip bootstrap
```

After the zip file has been generated, I have manually uploaded the zip file in the AWS console. This is done by selecting upload from '.zip file' under 'Code Source' in the 'Code' tab.

Once the zip file has been uploaded, I clicked on the 'Test' button in the 'Test' tab but an error was returned:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error"
}
```

I have tried to build a zip file on macOS instead and it works so I am unable to figure out why it doesn't work on a Windows laptop.